# Report Viewer Taking too long to load report

Tags: vb.net

i have a problem with my report viewer taking too long to load reports and sometimes it get some error while loading the report. Report viewer is loaded through dataset and stored procedure.

Is their any way to improve it. Just clicking the Print Preview button and displays the report fast enough to report viewer.

Please help.

This is the sample code in loading the report. it works fine but, sometimes it takes too long to load and sometimes error occur especially when clicking command buttons faster:

```
Me.CertificationofEnrollmentTableAdapter.Fill(Me.COEPrint.CertificationofEnrollment, CertificateofEnrollment.txtStudentID.Text, CertificateofEnrollment.cmbSemester.Text, CertificateofEnrollment.cmbSchoolYear.Text)        
          Me.ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
    ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ZoomMode.Percent

    Dim Parametrs As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter() = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter() {New 
    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("FirstStatement", 
    CertificateofEnrollment.RichTextBoxFS.Text.ToString()), New 
    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("SecondStatement", 
    CertificateofEnrollment.RichTextBox2.Text.ToString()), New 
    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Units", 
    CertificateofEnrollment.txtTotalUnits.Text.ToString()), New 
    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Signatory", 
    My.Settings.Sign3.ToString()), New 
    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Position", 
    My.Settings.Post3.ToString())}
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(Parametrs)

    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

I hope you can help me with this. its too slow.

Comment: I think this sort of question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ It's too broad here - and when you post the question, you should include relevant code. The error when loading the report is something that we might be able to help with tho. Add the relevant code, the error, what line it is happening on. and ideally a sample of data. Cheers

Comment: I added some code in my post..can you please help me with my problem. please...

Comment: `sometimes it get some error while loading the report`.  You need to tell us the error.

Comment: I forgot the error.. but is their any way of making the report viewer to load report more faster for just 1second or a millisecond maybe? please help i really need it..

Comment: Usually a query would be a bottleneck.

Comment: So their is no possibility of making it fast enough to load report?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug on the srystal report .. that I couldn't find logical answer on the web from a long time search

Ahmad AlAMahdi